# Breadcrumbs disappeared from single product and category pages after updating woocommerce to 2.3.6

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

My site BYnOb(dot)com working well before woo commerce updates, but after upgrading woo commerce to 2.3.6 version I faced a lot of errors and template outdated issues. I have successfully replaced outdated template files. I have solved many issues but still, I am facing one problem listed below:

Breadcrumbs have disappeared from the single product page and category pages. Screenshots links for the issue are attached as well. Please help.

http://pbrd.co/18vMcpf   (Screenshot for category pages)

http://pbrd.co/18vMj4i   (Screenshot for single product pages)

Regards:

Davisson

Answer (score 0):

Maybe updating your woocommerce has disabled breadcrumbs by default. You can try using yoast plugin to solve this problem. You can read about this in [here](http://webplantmedia.com/starter-themes/wordpresscanvas/breadcrumbs-woocommerce-shopping-page/)

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: thanks for your quick response but It did not work for me I tried it. Any other advise?

Davisson